# How can i rotate a title 270 degrees?

Tags: html, css, rotation, transform, tumblr

I have a website which i want to rotate a title 270deg on! I have seen many other posts about this but they don't seem to be working for me! Below is the code of the item i want to rotate! Where do i put the code and what do i put? 
I want to put it in this code! This is the whole segment for that text!

```
/* LOGO CSS*/
#logo_index_text a,
#logo_index_left a,
.logo_permalink_page
{
font-weight: {text:Weight Logo Index};
font-family: {font:Font Logo};
color: {color:Text Logo};
}
#logo_index_left{left:{text:Position Logo Left}}
#logo_index_left {top:{text:Position Logo Top}}
#logo_index_text a, 
#logo_index_left a
{
letter-spacing: {text:LetterSpacing Logo};
font-size: {text:FontSize Logo Index};
line-height: {text:LineHeight Logo}
}
{block:IfNotLogoOpacityonHover}
#logo_index_text a:hover, 
#logo_index_left a:hover{
opacity: 1 !important}
{/block:IfNotLogoOpacityonHover}
.logo_permalink_page{font-size: {text:FontSize Logo Perma}}
```

The code i have tried is:

```
-moz-transform: rotate(270deg);
-moz-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
-webkit-transform: rotate(270deg);
-webkit-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
```

and

```
-moz-transform: rotate(7.5deg);  /* FF3.5+ */
-o-transform: rotate(7.5deg);  /* Opera 10.5 */
-webkit-transform: rotate(7.5deg);  /* Saf3.1+, Chrome */
```

and

```
-webkit-transform: rotate(320deg);
-moz-transform: rotate(320deg);   
-o-transform: rotate(320deg);
```

Thanks for the help in advance! :)

Comment: What do you mean by "title"? Just some text you have on your page? Also, you might want to cool it with the exclamation points...

Comment: I actually hardly understand any of your LogoCss - can you put this in a fiddle?

Comment: I didn't code this. But a solution has been found now. Thanks anyway! :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the simplest place to start. To me your main logocss seems a bit of a mess, but bear in mind you need to have `display: block` for anything to rotate.

**Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jjBGz/3/**

Comment: happy to help. (and when you get the right answer, check the "right answer check" and upvote. Both good for me, you and the rest of the community.

Answer (score 1):

Beneth's method won't work if you have a background...
Here's the real trick: 
The secret is having vertical-lr set on the original element, so width and height are already correct. 
Then all you have to do is rotate the text 180 degrees with transform-origin center...

Works in Chrome and Firefox and IE 11 & 10 (according to MDN backwards-compatible to IE9, but since ms-transform-rotate doesn't work properly, it degrades gracefully to only writing-mode vertical-lr in IE9, if you omit ms-transform).

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-orientation
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/writing-mode#Browser_compatibility
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms531187(v=vs.85).aspx

Example:

```
.blackhd
{
    vertical-align: bottom;
    width: 40px;
    #height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid hotpink;
    background-color: black;
    text-align: center;
}

.vert
{
    display: inline-block;
    color: white;
    #font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 15px;
    writing-mode: vertical-lr;
    #writing-mode: vertical-rl;
    -ms-writing-mode: tb-rl;
    transform-origin: center;
    transform: rotate(180deg);
    padding-top: 2mm;
    padding-bottom: 3mm;
}


<table>
    <tr>
        <td class="blackhd"><span class="vert">abc</span></td>
        <td class="blackhd"><span class="vert">defghijkl</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>defghijklmnopqr</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```